# I'm trying to check if the user is registered in the sqlite3 database, but I get this error

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to check if the user is registered in the sqlite3 database, but I get this error: Error type: the handle 'execute' for objects 'sqlite3.Cursor' is not applied to the object 'str'

```
    data = None
        ## @dp.message_handler(commands = "reg", state = None)
def reg_user(message):
    global data
    people_id = message.chat.id
    Cursor.execute(f'SELECT user_id FROM data_user WHERE user_id = {people_id}')
    data = Cursor.fetchone()
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You need to create a cursor by calling a connection's `cursor()` method, not by doing `from sqlite3 import Cursor` or similar.  Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Where are you getting `Cursor` from?  Please [edit] your question to show this.

Comment: Not related to your question, but using string formatting in `execute()` is dangerous. https://bobby-tables.com